# Yet, another generalization of Catalan determinants

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants, catalan-numbers

The discussion on this page is motivated by [Johann Cigler's MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445707/determinants-of-band-matrices-which-are-related-to-hankel-matrices-of-catalan-nu). My intention arose from a possible generalization of Cigler's matrix
$$A_{n,m}=\left( \binom{2m}{j-i+m}-\binom{2m}{m-i-j-1} \right)_{0\leq {i,j} \leq {n-1}}.$$

Introduce a new parameter $x$ and the matrix
$$T_{n,m}(x):=\left(\binom{x+m}{j-i+m}-\binom{x+m}{m-i-j-1}\right)_{i,j=0}^{n-1}.$$

> **QUESTION.** Is this determinant evaluation true?
> $$\det T_{n,m}(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m\frac{(x+i-j)(x+2i+j-2)}{(x+2i-j)(i+j-1)}.$$

**Remark 1.** The relation $\det T_{n,m}(m)=\det A_{n,m}=\prod_{1\leq i\leq j\leq m-1}\frac{2n+i+j}{i+j}$ recovers that of [Cigler's determinant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445707/determinants-of-band-matrices-which-are-related-to-hankel-matrices-of-catalan-nu). The latter is connected to a host of other interpretations (see [recent MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446907/a-numerical-matrix-of-power-sum-polynomials)).

**Remark 2.** I am hoping that the structure of the new determinant would possibly make it easier to resolve [the earlier problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445707/determinants-of-band-matrices-which-are-related-to-hankel-matrices-of-catalan-nu) mentioned above.